# Bad Viewports Using Unity with Google Cardboard VR on iOS

Tags: unity, ios, google-cardboard

I'm using unity 2017.3.1f1, building for an iPhone SE.

I'm able to build the google HelloVR scene, available from the Google Cardboard VR unity package. However, in the end result, the cameras are giving the wrong display. They aren't lined up to create stereoscopic vision at all, and the image appears distorted.

Here is an example of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ95v.jpg

Is there a default setting in the Google Cardboard VR package that can be changed to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug, documented here with workaround: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/838